# Selecting fruits from an urn

Tags: combinatorics

> An urn contains $3$ mangoes, $4$ mangoes and, $5$ oranges. Find the number of ways of selecting the fruits taking one of them at a time.

I can't quite understand the inherent meaning of this question and what I interpret is that how many different sequences of the three fruits can be built? So, the answer should be:

$$  \frac{12!}{3! \cdot 4! \cdot 5!} $$

But the book's answer is:

> $$(3+1)(4+1)(5+1) - 1 = 119.$$

How are they interpreting the problem to make this the correct answer?

Comment: A mango is a mango is a mango, as Gertrude Stein might have said.

Comment: I believe your interpretation, and your answer, are both correct.

Comment: A mango is a fruit. A mango is edible. We humans eat it. Some animals eat it. I know a person named Mango.

A mango is more than just a mango, or what we all think.

Comment: @MJD The book answer is $119$. Derivation given is :

$(3+1)(4+1)(5+1)-1=119$

Comment: That's the sort of thing you should have said in the first place!  No wonder you are puzzled.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. There are two ways to fix this question that I can see: change the oranges to mangoes, so that the answer is 1; or change one of those mangoes to grapes, so that the question makes sense. (Another possibility is that green mangled the question in translation $-$ some languages presumably have more words for "mango" than English does.)

Answer (score 0):

in the above problem they have asked the number of ways selecting the fruits taking one at a time. but you have found out the number of ways the 12 fruits can be arranged.
the interpretation of books answer is:
3 mangoes can be selected in 4 ways since we can select the 1st , 2nd or the 3rd mango or none of them....
similarly we have 5 ways for selecting next 4 mangoes and 6 ways in selecting 5 oranges. so the total no of ways is = 4*5*6 =120.
but we have included the case where we have selected none....
so the final answer is 120-1=119 ways!!